# Finding the normal vector

Tags: vectors

I've got this question:

---

A opaque ball in the space with center $(10,0,-1)$ with
radius with $r = 1$. A ray tracing program is tracing a ray from the eye position $(0,0,10)$ with the ray direction
$(1,0,-1)$.

---

I've figured out that the ray will strike the ball at $(10,0,0)$, but how do I  find the normal vector at this intersection point?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $C=(a,b,c)^T$ is the center of a sphere of radius $R$ and $P=(x_P,y_P,z_P)^T$ is a point on the sphere, the normal vector to the sphere in $P$ is a unitary vector parallel to the radius in $P$:
$$
\vec n=\frac{1}{R}(a-x_P,b-y_P,c-z_P)^T
$$